# @react-native-firebase integration with react-redux-firebase V3

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, redux, react-redux

Does anyone know how to integrate @react-native-firebase with react-redux-firebase V3 ?

I have installed react-native-firebase following this tutorial https://rnfirebase.io/

```
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^12.1.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^12.1.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^12.1.0",
    ...
  },
```

The [git code](https://github.com/prescottprue/react-redux-firebase/tree/master/examples/complete/react-native-firebase) how to implement react-redux-firebase with react-native seems to be deprecated as it still using the **V2**

**The [documentation on the website](http://react-redux-firebase.com/docs/integrations/react-native.html) :**

- use firebase without importation when configuring the store ?
- use import from 'react-redux-firebase' and not '@react-redux-firebase/...' (what is the difference ?)

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import RNFirebase from 'react-native-firebase';
import { createStore, combineReducers, compose } from 'redux'
import { ReactReduxFirebaseProvider, firebaseReducer } from 'react-redux-firebase'
// import { createFirestoreInstance, firestoreReducer } from 'redux-firestore' // <- needed if using firestore

...

// Initialize firebase instance
firebase.initializeApp(fbConfig)
```

**Does anyone know how to integrate correctly @react-native-firebase with react-redux-firebase V3 ?**

Comment: I'm also stuck on this now. Did you manage to figure it out?

Comment: @TarunSharma yes, look at my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution,

You will need to import modules like this
and also retrieve an instance of firebase with the app() function.

Here is my **configStore** file

```js
import {createStore, applyMiddleware, compose} from 'redux';
import rootReducer from '../Redux/Reducers/rootReducer';
import middlewares from '../Redux/Middleware/middleware';
import {createFirestoreInstance} from 'redux-firestore'; // <- needed if using firestore
import {persistReducer, persistStore} from 'redux-persist';
import rrfConfig from '../Redux/Config/reactReduxFirebaseConfig';
import persistConfig from '../Redux/Config/persistConfig';

// Cherry-pick modules of react-native-firebase 6.x
// import '@react-native-firebase/analytics';
// import '@react-native-firebase/crashlytics';
// import '@react-native-firebase/dynamic-links';
// import '@react-native-firebase/perf';
// import '@react-native-firebase/remote-config';
import '@react-native-firebase/auth';
import '@react-native-firebase/firestore';
import '@react-native-firebase/database';
import '@react-native-firebase/storage';

import RNfirebase from '@react-native-firebase/app';
const firebase = RNfirebase.app(); // <-- Retrieve an instance of a FirebaseApp.

// persist reducer in storage
const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

// Create store with reducers
const store = createStore(
  persistedReducer,
  compose(applyMiddleware(...middlewares)),
);

// react-redux-firebase props
export const rrfProps = {
  firebase,
  config: rrfConfig,
  dispatch: store.dispatch,
  createFirestoreInstance, // <- needed if using firestore
};

export const persistor = persistStore(store);

export default store;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been struggling with this for days. For me it was the `RNfirebase.app()` call that did the trick. I spent a lot of time trying to get it to work via the `RNfirebase.initializeApp()` method. That method has a looooot of config options where it's really easy to get bogged down. Also nowhere in the docs does it say that `@react-native-firebase/database` is needed, so thanks a lot for that too.